# How can i use AsyncTask in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

i am trying to use AsyncTask  task in fragment but i couldn get value. i use it in Activity without problem. But i couldn do in fragment. How can i solve this problem.        Sorry for my eng.

this is my error:

```
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730): Process: com.isosoft.vale, PID: 28730
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at com.isosoft.vale.Kayit$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(Kayit.java:401)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at com.isosoft.vale.Kayit$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(Kayit.java:1)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-25 11:19:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(28730):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: what is the line at at com.isosoft.vale.Kayit$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(Kayit.java:401) ?

Comment: what is at the `Kayit.java:401`?

Comment: your java file name is Kayit.java , right?

Comment: Yes @AmitK.Saha please give the code with line no. or give a comment in which line error occurs

Comment: yes kayit.java is class

Comment: what is the code at line no 401?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess as it is NullPointerException of your crash,

this is your problematic line -

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

you might be getting `null` from `getActivity()`. From which state/method you are executing your asynctask obj?

### Updated Answer

in your asynctask you used **global**

```
String URL = "http://" + global.getDBHosturl() + "/myvale/valeservis.asmx";
```

but as I see, your **global** is initialised as

```
GlobalClass global = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
```

and you also have -

```
private GlobalClass getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

so basically your **global** is `null` and thus you are getting NPE. Hope this helps.

And it seems you tried to override following these 2 method by mistakes-

```
private GlobalClass getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private com.isosoft.vale.CustomAutoCompleteTextView findViewById(
        int txtModel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I believe you should delete them.

Comment: no, my friend when i remove that again i am getting same error.

Comment: what is there at line 401, can't you tell us that specific line? plus the answer was given on guess (when you didn't share the full code).

Comment: @IsmailOzkan, please see my updated answer, if that solves your problem.